# Issue with Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to accomplish the following with the Google Maps API:

- Display `to_address` as a marker on the map
- Get users location
- Generate and display directions based on the information given by gps/user input

I have gotten the last two to work just fine. The problem I am having now is showing the `to_address` as a marker on the map if the location is not provided.

This is the code I am using. Keep in mind the last 2 steps work as expected. I know that I can accomplish this using latlng but that is not an option for me. I need to provide it an address.

```
var geocoder;
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var to_pos;
var to_address = '11161 84th ave delta bc';

function initialize() {

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();


    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': to_address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            to_pos = results[0].geometry.location;
        }
    });

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: to_pos
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));

    var control = document.getElementById('d_options');

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title: "You"
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);
            $('#from').val(pos);
            $('#d_options').trigger('collapse');
            calcRoute();

        }, function () {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    }
}

function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('from').value;
    var end = to_address;
    $('#results').show();
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geocoding uses an asynchronous request. You must create the marker inside the callback of geocode()

```
geocoder.geocode({
        'address': to_address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var to_pos = results[0].geometry.location;

            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(to_pos.lat(),to_pos.lng()),
                map: map,
                title: "Destination"
            });
        }
    });
```